# Convert Html to pdf with images

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, html-pdf

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF so i used TCPDF its PHP plugin.
that is the official site for it 
[TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)

it was working well but its so limited tool and it has limited fonts

And it cant convert images to PDF so how can i convert full HTML page with images to PDF file, it dose not matter if it JS or PHP plugin , i just want active solution to convert the whole HTML page with Css to PDF file and maybe i will save it or print it

Comment: use this library `https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf`

Comment: Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: for images you have to convert the image to base64 and embed it into the html and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('#showPdf').click(function() {
      var pdf = new jsPDF();  
      pdf.addHTML($("#divContent"), function() {
     var blob = pdf.output("blob");
        window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      });
    });
$('#downloadPdf').click(function() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF();  
  pdf.addHTML($("#divContent"), function() {
 pdf.save('pageContent.pdf');
  });
});
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="divContent" style="background-color: white; padding:20px 25px">
      <h3>SEA MINK</h3>
      <p>The sea mink (Neovison macrodon) was a mammal from the eastern coast
      of North America, in the family of weasels and otters in the order Carnivora.
      The largest of the minks, it was hunted to extinction by fur traders before 1903,
      when it was first given a species description. Some biologists classify it as a subspecies of the
      American mink. Estimates of its size are speculative, based largely on skull fragments recovered 
      from Native American shell middens, and on tooth remains. Some information on its appearance and 
      habits was provided by fur traders and Native Americans. It may have been similar in behavior to
      the American mink: it probably maintained home ranges, was polygynandrous, and had a similar diet, 
      supplemented by saltwater prey. Sea minks were commonly trapped along the coast of the Bay of
      Fundy in the Gulf of Maine. Remains have been found along the New England coast, and there were r
      egular reports of unusually large mink furs, probably sea mink, being collected from Nova Scotia</p>
      
      <img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
      </div>
      <button id="showPdf">Generate PDF</button>
<button id="downloadPdf">Download PDF</button>




Try this code in your browser for better result.
```

Comment: thank you its working but how i will convert the image auto from url to base64 because i want to make form it will generate the pdf automatically

Comment: i hope vote up to my question i dont know why they voted negative for me

Comment: @E-housmaMardini you have downvotes because your question is off-topic. Take a read through the [help]. Other users commented on your question explaining why already before this comment you just made.

Comment: @E-housmaMardini The answer works but the question is about PHP not javascript. Admins hate that for SEO reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>


function CreatePDFfromHTML(e) {
    var HTML_Width = $("#imageDIV").width();
    var HTML_Height = $("#imageDIV").height();
    // alert(HTML_Width); // HTML_Height=3800; // HTML_Width=1349;
    var top_left_margin = 15;
    var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 5);
    var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
    var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;
    var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;
    html2canvas($("#imageDIV")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
        for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
            pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 15), canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
        }
        pdf.save("calendar.pdf");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.